# Export apk with proguard enabled fails with message: Failed to Export

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, proguard

Trying to export APK, with Proguard enabled, results in error: Failed to Export.

Here is what my configuration looks like:

**project.properties**

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat
```

proguard-android-optimize.txt - everything in this is default.
proguard-project.txt - everything in this file is commented.

**In eclipse logs** i see these:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.createWindowsProguardConfig(BuildHelper.java:652)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.runProguard(BuildHelper.java:571)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:259)
```

*Wonder why the NullPointer - Am i missing any configuration?*
Eclipse ADT version is probably 23 (Help > About - does not show anything)

Answer (score 0):

The sdk\tools\proguard\bin contained proguard.sh file, and not proguard.bat file - which is what export process was looking for (Eclipse ADT on Windows 7 laptop). 
Not sure why the .bat files were not present by default though.

So, placing proguard.bat there helped, and export with proguard enabled started working 
This is what progaurd.bat looks like in case you do not have it:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Start-up script for ProGuard -- free class file shrinker, optimizer,
REM obfuscator, and preverifier for Java bytecode.
REM
REM Note: when passing file names containing spaces to this script,
REM       you'll have to add escaped quotes around them, e.g.
REM       "\"C:/My Directory/My File.txt\""

IF EXIST "%PROGUARD_HOME%" GOTO home
SET PROGUARD_HOME=..
:home

java -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*
```